# Removing and Adding TextGeometry freezes the scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create a clock with the help of Text Geometry. In order to update the time I need to update the text in  Text Geometry which can be done by removing and recreating a new Text Geometry.

Every time I add a new Text Geometry it freezes my browser:

```
 // Remove old mesh
  earthClockMesh.geometry.dispose();
  earthClockMesh.material.dispose();
  group.remove(earthClockMesh);


   //add new mesh
  earthClockMesh = this.getTextMesh(
    new Date(diluatedTime).toLocaleString(),
    textMaterial
  );
  group.add(earthClockMesh);
```

Anybody know better way way we can update the text in Text Geometry without freezing browser.

**Live Example**

https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-boyd-x859m

You can see the particles gets freeze for a moment when TextGeometry changed

Comment: Can you please demonstrate the freeze with a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/)? I've never experienced such an error with `TextGeometry` before. BTW: Instead of creating `TextGeometry`, create an instance of `TextBufferGeometry` and see if it helps.

Comment: Updated answer with live example. Look at Line #157 : updateTextGeometry method of Clock class.  I have used TextBufferGeometry and it had same result.

Comment: I'd like to clarify that the freeze does only endure a short moment when creating the geometry. The performance can be improved if you directly create `THREE.TextBufferGeometry` and lower the amount of `curveSegments` like in this live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-satoshi-go9ml

Comment: @Mugen87 you can add a answer if you want to. I will mark that answer as accepted answer and we can close this thread.

Comment: Okay, I'll add an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `THREE.TextBufferGeometry` will improve the performance since it produces much less object allocation than `TextGeometry`. Besides, each instance of `THREE.Geometry` is internally converted to `THREE.BufferGeometry` before the first rendering. If you additionally lower the amount of `curveSegments`, the should be almost no noticeable lag anymore.

`three.js R107`

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that you're deleting the generated geometry, then re-building thousands and thousands of triangles each second. This is very computationally expensive, and you see the animation freeze while the CPU tries to catch up. This is what you're doing:

1. Text geometry gets disposed
2. CPU re-builds all characters with an updated second (first bottleneck)
3. New geometry data gets passed to GPU (second bottleneck)
4. Scene gets rendered smoothly while no geom is being rebuilt

With real-time graphics (videogames, visualizers, etc), the geometry construction typically happens at the beginning of the app to avoid these mid-game stutters. Try to generate the geometry *only once*, then swap it out as necessary:

1. Create a "dictionary" of all 16 necessary characters as individual `Mesh` objects: `0123456789:/APM,`
2. With this base dictionary, you can [`.clone()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.clone) the needed characters, then place them with `.position`. You can use `.clone(false)`.
3. At the end of each second, `.clone()` the geometry from the dictionary into the few characters you need to update.

The beauty of cloning Meshes like this is that the geometry is only generated once. You don't need to spend tons of processing power re-building it.